# Telnet and X11 forwarding in version 16.04

Tags: networking, server, xorg

X11 redirection from a legacy Solaris server broke when upgrading from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.  Connection to the legacy server is via telnet.  In version 14.04, xhost+ was used before establishing the telnet connection and redirection worked.  When the same steps are tried in version 16.04, error message is "Error: Can't open display".  DISPLAY Env variable is set correctly on legacy server but redirect seems to be blocked on ubuntu 16.04 side.  Is there a config file which needs an entry change?  Desktop manager is unity.